# Please can someone help me find my mistake in my solution of non-linear system

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, matlab, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

I've recently been attempting to analytically solve a non-linear model for stick-slip friction and although I can find the correct Jacobian matrix when I try to solve the equation to find the equilibrium point I get a different answer for the x coordinate than I get if I simulate it in Matlab. I was wondering if anyone can help me find my mistake. Pictures attached show my written work and the matlab simulation

Thanks

[Matlab simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SyFx.png)[Attempt at analytical solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um8lo.jpg)

[Typed up attempt at solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L5ki.png)

Comment: Could you type up your work so it is easier to read?

Comment: I've typed my solution now and added it as another image. Hope this is now clearer